# what does 'function(x){!any(is.na(x))})]' mean exactly in my function 'descr.mol[,apply(descr.mol,2, function(x){!any(is.na(x))})]'

Tags: r

```
descr.mol.noNa <- descr.mol[,apply(descr.mol,2, function(x){!any(is.na(x))})]
```

I had to run this line for an assignment to remove all the 'NA' values from my file 'descr.mol',  but I was wondering how exactly it works. My homework does not provide further explanation or a breakdown of the code. I figured is.na(x) searches for all the NA values in my object x, which in this case is descr.mol, but that's about all I could figure out, and it would be great to fully understand the line for future reference, I think.

Comment: It reduces the returned collection from `is.na` to a boolean and inverts.

Comment: A faster and better understandable solution might be `descr.mol[, colSums(is.na(descr.mol)) == 0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explaination of `!any(is.na(x))`

In plain English `!any` (not any) means "none".

`is.na()` returns a boolean vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` for a given vector, where `TRUE` means that a value is missing. `!any()` returns `TRUE` if none of the values are missing, and `FALSE` if at least one value is missing.

Example:

```r
vec1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
vec2 <- c(1, 2, NA)

is.na(vec1)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
is.na(vec2)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

!any(is.na(vec1))
#> [1] TRUE
!any(is.na(vec2))
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### Explaination of your code

Your code does the following:

- it creates an anonymous function which returns `TRUE` if there are no NA values in the input, using the logic explained above
- it uses `apply` to apply this function to all columns of `desc.mol`, this returns a vector of `TRUE` / `FALSE` for each column in `desc.mol`
- this vector is then used to subset the original data by column, so that only columns without `NA` values are kept

Here is a reprex with `airquality`:

```r
df <- head(airquality)

df
#>   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
#> 1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
#> 2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
#> 3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
#> 4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
#> 5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
#> 6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6

df[, apply(df, 2, function(x) {!any(is.na(x))})]
#>   Wind Temp Month Day
#> 1  7.4   67     5   1
#> 2  8.0   72     5   2
#> 3 12.6   74     5   3
#> 4 11.5   62     5   4
#> 5 14.3   56     5   5
#> 6 14.9   66     5   6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### A tidy alternative

Here is the way I would do the same, using a tidy approach:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(where(~!any(is.na(.x))))
#>   Wind Temp Month Day
#> 1  7.4   67     5   1
#> 2  8.0   72     5   2
#> 3 12.6   74     5   3
#> 4 11.5   62     5   4
#> 5 14.3   56     5   5
#> 6 14.9   66     5   6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>